# Selecting a cell and copiying the corresponding cells in the row in VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to build a macro and I want to copy a row after selecting a specific cell with the filter. So I filter a cell in column "A" and then I want to copy all the cells in that row. The problem is that the rownumber corresponding to the selected cell may change, due to different datasets.

Below is the code:

```
Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$DO$46").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "NAME"
    Range("A5:DO5").Select
    Selection.Copy
```

The point is that in VBA the selection is set at "A5:DO5", because in this specific dataset "NAME" is on "A5".

But in a different dataset "NAME" might be on "A9", but in VBA the selection of the row is still on "A5:DO5".

How can I make the selection of "NAME" and the copy of all the cells in the row of "NAME" linked to eachother?

Answer (score 0):

I think the question could be a bit clearer, but here goes.

As I understand it you want to copy a row, say 5th row down, after a filter has been applied to hide some rows in between (5th visible row).
Or, you want to find "NAME" and copy the corresponding row, irrespective of what's hidden and what isn't.

(If I haven't got the above right, please let me know and/or consider clarifying the question)

Try something like this;

```
Dim C as Cell
Dim RowNum as Integer 'If you're looking for the 5th visible cell.

For each C in Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xltypeVisible)
    RowNum = RowNum+1 'Count how many visible cells you've looped
    If C.Value = "NAME" Then
    'Or for the 5th visible cell, use 'If RowNum = 5 Then'
        C.EntireRow.Copy
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. Unlukily, the code is not working.

To clarify:

I want to find "NAME" in Column "B" and copy the corresponding row of "NAME", irrespective of what's hidden and what isn't.

Now I have this code:

```
Dim C As Range
For Each C In Range("B:B")
If C.Value = "NAME" Then
C.EntireRow.Copy
Exit For
End If
Next
```

The code does copy a row, but not the row that corresponds with "NAME". Instead, it copies the first row in the active sheet.

Comment: I will edit my original answer now that I understand the question. Thanks for that.

Comment: Important note here, does the cell you're looking at contain the quotation marks, or were you just putting them in for grammar? Are we searching for `NAME` or `"NAME"` ?

Comment: Because in order to insert quotation marks in a string they have to be doubled, to show they're part of the string rather than defining the start and end of the string

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I solved it with another solution:

 Range("B:B").Find("NAME").Select
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy

This way it works out fine!